# Rugged error on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rugged

When I ran the following:

`r = Rugged::Repository.new('<myrepopath>')`

I got the following error:

`Rugged::OSError: The global/xdg file 'config' doesn't exist: The system cannot find the path specified.`

How should I resolve it?

I'm using `rugged 0.19.0` on Windows 7 and `ruby -v` outputs `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]` on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem after installing the "gem install rugged" on Windows using DevKit.
At the time I investigated the underlying problem and reported it, and I think artherschreiber committed a fix to the rugged repo on GitHub.  I can't remember the details, and the fix might have been to libgit2 with rugged pulling in the libgit2 fix.
Unfortunately I don't think the released gem has been updated, so it doesn't pick up this fix.

At the time, I think I found that using a 32-bit Ruby, installing MSys / MinGW, and running "gem install rugged" from an MSys bash prompt did give a working version of rugged.